# linux add ip route then restore the old routes

Tags: linux, routes

I have a small software which connects to a pptp VPN server. It adds a route on `if-up.d` which routes all traffic through the VPN `ip route change default via $PPP_LOCAL dev $IFNAME`

Problem is that when I disconnect the VPN/close the software, the pptp connection closes but the routes are not restored. I've also added a delete route command in the `if-down.d` section to delete this route `ip route del default via $PPP_LOCAL dev $IFNAME` but my internet stops working. I have to "Disable/Enable networking" to have internet again.

Comment: why do I get close votes on this question? What is ur problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess since I have no way of testing it, but instead of changing the default-route, could you just add another with a lower metric?

Comment: Well, when you disconnect, you delete the default-route that you added, and the system will return to using the previous default-route (i.e. the one with the higher metric)

Comment: well I've set it with metric 1 with 0 being my default route but it wont use it. It uses the default one instead and my traffic is not routed through the ppp0 interface. Here's a sample of routes before and after I've added based on your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/jim6LhLc

Comment: never mind, I managed to get it going by deleting the route, adding it with a metric of 1 then adding mine with a metric of 0 and it works.

Comment: Yeah, numerically-lower-metric == higher-priority.